# Query the Windows event log in a performant way

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I've built an ASP.NET web app to view data from the Windows Event Log using databound controls.  The data is retrieved via an `ObjectDataSource` connected to a mediator class that accesses the `EventLog`.  When I connect a `GridView` to the `ObjectDataSource`, it wants to count the rows in the `EventLog`. I can do this simply and quickly with:

```
var log = new EventLog {Log = logName};
return log.Entries.Count;
```

From my unscientific perspective, it appears to be returning in O(1).  However, if I want to count entries that occur before a certain date or that are via a certain  event source, I cannot find a way to count them that is efficient.  I've tried WMI queries such as:

```
var query = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent
                             where LogFile='Application'");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
var result = searcher.Get();
var foo = result.Count;
```

For an event log with 70k entries, this takes on the order of a minute on my reasonably powered workstation.  It's looking like O(n).  I've also tried filtering `log.Entries` with Linq and get similar results.

Is there any more performant way to do this?  For the actual data in the grid, I've found looping over the `log.Entries` and accessing via index a very performant way to get a collection of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or above, then you can use the [EventLogQuery class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogquery.aspx) and related APIs.

Comment: I have to add that although this indeed is very fast, it requires that the guest OS and the OS that you are querying both are Vista above version. I ran into this issue now and got stuck.